# grails render html filetype

Tags: grails

I'm interfacing with some display code in html files, that folks want to keep in that file type due to tools they are using.

What's the easiest way for me to render it from a controller action?   As far as I understand [render](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Controllers/render.html) can't specify an html filetype.  Should this ultimately be changed, or is there an easy workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I thought render( contentType: 'text/csv', text: ... )  will set your type.

If that doesn't work, you could try going setting this in the response.

response.contentType = "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"
response.outputStream << "